# setAdapter crashes app in onItemSelected in Fragment

Tags: java, android, dataadapter

I want my app to change other spinners items when other spinners selected item changed But when I setAdapter for spinner app crashes. Btw I think it calls onItemSelectd method 4 times when app starts first. Might it be the problem? Here is my code:

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
        {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            if( parent.getId() == R.id.aySpinner)
            {               
                Spinner gunSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.gunSpinner);


                // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
                String ay = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                if( ay.equals("Ocak"))
                {

                    for(int i = 1; i<=31; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }

                }
                else if( ay.equals("Şubat") )
                {

                    for(int i = 1; i<=28; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }
                }
                else if( ay.equals("Mart") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=31; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }

                }
                else if( ay.equals("Nisan") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=30; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }

                }
                else if( ay.equals("Mayıs") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=31; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }

                }
                else if( ay.equals("Haziran") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=30; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }
                }
                else if( ay.equals("Temmuz") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=31; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }

                }
                else if( ay.equals("Ağustos") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=31; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }

                }
                else if( ay.equals("Eylül") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=30; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }

                }
                else if( ay.equals("Ekim") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=31; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }   

                }
                else if( ay.equals("Kasım") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=30; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }
                }
                else if( ay.equals("Aralık") )
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i<=31; ++i )
                    {
                        String foo = Integer.toString(i);
                        list.add(foo);
                    }

                }

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            gunSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            }

        }
```

****EDIT***

I have solved the problem. I don't know why this problem occurs but when I change this line:

```
Spinner gunSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.gunSpinner);
```

to this:

```
Spinner gunSpinner = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gunSpinner);
```

it works. Thanks for helps and sorry for unnecessary post.

Comment: Provide logcat output with stack-trace of Exception thrown.

Comment: Check my edited post I add the answer

Comment: The reason that worked was because the view that is passed in to the onItemSelected is the row that was clicked. The row you clicked does not contain the spinner so when you do view.findViewById it does not find a spinner with id gunSpinner thus returning null. When you run that on Activity it will search the entire view tree of the activity to find the view with id gunSpinner.

Comment: It is logical. Thanks for your explanation